# socket_read byte by byte

Tags: php, sockets

I observe a strange behavior on socket read, with a timeout on read operations, when my program read byte per byte : only the beginning of the message is read, and then 'socket_read' return false.
If the read operations are done on two bytes or more, all the message is returned.

Bellow is the source code of the socket creation function and of the socket read function.

In the read function, there is a timestamp of 300 set before to read. This timestamp does not work for read operations byte per byte, since the message "BEGIN read" and "END read" are written in log file with less than one second interval.

The program need to read byte per byte to stop on a particular marker.

Anybody has an idea to enable read byte per byte with a blocking read ?

Thanks for any help !

```
<?php


function getSocket($port, $address)
{
    // Ouverture de la socket en attente de connexion
    if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
        detectedErrorLog("socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");
        return false;
    }

    //rendre la socket réutilisable (plus d'erreur "address already in use")
    if (socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) === false) {
        detectedErrorLog("socket_set_option SO_REUSEADDR failed : " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");
        return false;
    }

    //la connexion doit être maintenue ouverte
    if (socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1) === false) {
        detectedErrorLog("socket_set_option SO_KEEPALIVE failed : " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
        detectedErrorLog("socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (socket_listen($sock) === false) {
        detectedErrorLog( "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n");
        return false;
    }

    return $sock;
}

function mySocketRead($msgsock, $length, $delimiter)
{
    $message = "";
    $cpt = 0;
    $nb_octets = 1;

    socket_set_option($msgsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>300, 'usec'=>0));

    $rand_number = rand();
    debugLog("BEGIN read (".$rand_number."): ".time().", timeout lecture = ".print_r(socket_get_option($msgsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO), true));

    while($cpt < $length) 
    {
        $resp = socket_read($msgsock, $nb_octets);

        if($resp !== false)
        {
            $message .= $resp;
            $cpt+=strlen($resp);
        }

        //S'il n'y a plus rien à lire ou qu'on arrive à la fin du message
        if ($resp == false || strpos($resp, $delimiter) !== false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    debugLog("END read (".$rand_number."): ".time().", message = ".$message);

    return $message;
}

?>
```

Comment: Check `socket_last_error` if you get `false` as a result

Comment: I already do that, it returned "success", that's all...